# HeadlessUI has a Transition error message only in Firefox

Tags: reactjs, firefox, next.js, tailwind-css, headless-ui

I am using Tailwind and HeadlessUI in my Next JS project and am seeing this issue when trying to open the app only on Firefox

> Unhandled Runtime Error
>
> Error: A <Transition /> is used but it is missing a `show={true | false}` prop.

I think it would be coming from this code section below. But the confusing part is there is no issue opening it on Chrome and this is the same way that Transition is used in the HeadlessUI docs.

```
<Menu as="div" className="z-50">
  <Menu.Button className="flex items-center h-full">
    <>
      {user?.displayName && (
        <span className="pl-2">{user.displayName}</span>
      )}
      <UserCircleIcon
          className="w-10 h-10 p-2"
          aria-label="account options"
      />
    </>
  </Menu.Button>
  <Transition
    as={React.Fragment}
    enter="transition ease-out duration-100"
    enterFrom="transform opacity-0 scale-95"
    enterTo="transform opacity-100 scale-100"
    leave="transition ease-in duration-75"
    leaveFrom="transform opacity-100 scale-100"
    leaveTo="transform opacity-0 scale-95"
  >
    <Menu.Items className="absolute z-30 flex flex-col justify-start w-auto mt-4 origin-top-right rounded-md shadow-lg right-4 menu-items ring-1 ring-black ring-opacity-5 focus:outline-none bg-primary-background">
      {user ? (
        <>
          <Menu.Item>
            {({ active }) => (
              <MyLink href="/account" active={active}>
                Account settings
              </MyLink>
            )}
          </Menu.Item>
          <Menu.Item>
            {({ active }) => (
              <MyButton onClick={handleSignOut} active={active}>
                Logout
              </MyButton>
            )}
          </Menu.Item>
        </>
      ) : (
        <>
          <Menu.Item>
            {({ active }) => (
              <MyLink href="/login" active={active}>
                Sign In
              </MyLink>
            )}
          </Menu.Item>
          <Menu.Item>
            {({ active }) => (
              <MyLink href="/signup" active={active}>
                Create Account
              </MyLink>
            )}
          </Menu.Item>
        </>
      )}
    </Menu.Items>
  </Transition>
</Menu>
```

Tried using a HeadlesUI Transition as shown in the docs for a Menu component but it does not work in Firefox only

Comment: As the error message says, you should add `show` as prop into `Transition` component with value between True | False

Comment: The problem with that is then the Menu is either always open or closed when it is set that way. The Menu component is supposed to manage where the Transition is showing or not like is shown in the docs:
https://headlessui.com/react/menu

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found another error message that led to the solution:

```
The above error occurred in the <ForwardRef> component:

q<@webpack-internal:///./node_modules/@headlessui/react/dist/components/transitions/transition.js:17:6747
CartPopup@webpack-internal:///./components/ui/cart/CartPopup.tsx:32:64
LoadableImpl@webpack-internal:///./node_modules/next/dist/shared/lib/loadable.js:65:9
div
Layout@webpack-internal:///./components/Layout.tsx:33:17
Home@webpack-internal:///./pages/index.tsx:17:19
StoreProvider@webpack-internal:///./utils/Store.tsx:151:20
FirebaseAuthProvider@webpack-internal:///./utils/firebase/firebaseAuth.tsx:60:20
MyApp@webpack-internal:///./pages/_app.tsx:15:21
ErrorBoundary@webpack-internal:///./node_modules/next/dist/compiled/@next/react-dev-overlay/dist/client.js:8:20742
ReactDevOverlay@webpack-internal:///./node_modules/next/dist/compiled/@next/react-dev-overlay/dist/client.js:8:23633
Container@webpack-internal:///./node_modules/next/dist/client/index.js:70:24
AppContainer@webpack-internal:///./node_modules/next/dist/client/index.js:216:20
Root@webpack-internal:///./node_modules/next/dist/client/index.js:407:21

React will try to recreate this component tree from scratch using the error boundary you provided, ErrorBoundary. 2
```

I looked into my CartPopup component which is using Transition but it does use the show prop. It turned out to be the variable I was using to set the show prop to true | false was coming from my Store Context and for some reason was not getting a value on initial load. I changed it to be set to false by default when getting the state from `useContext` and it started working

```js
const { state, dispatch } = useContext(Store);
const {
  cart: { cartItems, popUp = false } // Added '= false' to set popUp by default
} = state;

...

<Transition show={popUp} ... />
```

Comment: Turned out the whole initial stated for my Store Context Provider was not getting set properly so everything was null. I started seeing other errors pop up for first time users

Answer (score 0):

Your code is correct based on Headless UI docs. Might be an issue on their side. You can try to provide the `open` prop as show below, you can use the `open` prop provided by `<Menu/>` to directly pass it to the `<Transition/>`.

```js
<Menu as="div" className="z-50">
  {
    ({open}) => {
      return (
        <Menu.Button className="flex items-center h-full">
          //...
        </Menu.Button>
        <Transition
          show={open}
          as={React.Fragment}
          enter="transition ease-out duration-100"
          enterFrom="transform opacity-0 scale-95"
          enterTo="transform opacity-100 scale-100"
          leave="transition ease-in duration-75"
          leaveFrom="transform opacity-100 scale-100"
          leaveTo="transform opacity-0 scale-95"
        >
          <Menu.Items className="...">
            //...
          </Menu.Items>
        </Transition>
      )
    }
  }
</Menu>
```